# Data type mismatch VB.net and Access Database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

On my Delete button click event I am getting a Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters. In my Access Database CustNo is a DataType of Short Text

```
    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

    Dim custNumber As String
    custNumber = txtCustNo.Text
    Dim command As OleDbCommand


    Dim deleteQuery As String = "DELETE FROM TblLabelCustom_copy WHERE [CustNo]= @custNo"
    command = New OleDbCommand(deleteQuery)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = custNumber
    ExecuteQuery(deleteQuery)
    loadGrid()

End Sub
```

Comment: Wrap @custNo in single quotes (e.g '@custNo').  String values need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL.

Comment: @RogerMKE I have it working thanks for the help! do you have any links that will help me learn about how to add a datagridviewcheckboxcolumn value to the database. I have the values as 0 or 1

Comment: @GNell It should be `Add`, not `AddWithValue`.

Comment: @RogerMKE, that's not correct. That's a parameter, not a text literal, so you don't wrap it in single-quotes.  One of the advantages of using parameters is that you don't have to care about data types and work out what values need quotes or not.

Comment: @GNell, the comments on a question are not a place to ask completely unrelated questions.